# Undefined behaviour when function return type is not int

Tags: c, function

Consider `snippet 1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float val;
    val = fun(2, 4);
    printf("%f", val);
    
    return 0;
}
float fun(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

Code `snippet 2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int val;
    val = fun(2, 4);
    printf("%d", val);
    
    return 0;
}
int fun(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

In case of snippet 1, it gives me error, as follows:

```
gcc /tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c -lm
/tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c:6:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fun' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |     val = fun(2, 4);
      |           ^~~
/tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c: At top level:
/tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c:11:7: error: conflicting types for 'fun'
   11 | float fun(int x, int y){
      |       ^~~
/tmp/1cUl25Ux4O.c:6:11: note: previous implicit declaration of 'fun' was here
    6 |     val = fun(2, 4);
      |           ^~~
```

But in case of second snippet, i'm getting correct output. (i.e `6`).
In both the cases I've omitted function declaration and just the definition part is present, and that too after main().
But, if incase of `snippet 1`, if i change the order and define fun(int, int) before main(), i'm getting the desired output.(i.e `6.0000`)
I'm not able to figure it out.

Why is this happening?
Is it due to the order in which functions are pushed into stack?
If that is the reason, then why code in snippet 2 is working?
Please provide me either with references/ explanation. Thanks!

**Update:**
In the error log for snippet 1, it says that there are `conflicting types for fun`. But there's just one fun(int, int) present in the code. What is creating conflict?

Comment: `Why is this happening?` Because `warning: implicit declaration of function 'fun'`. Implicit declarations always assume `int` as return type.

Comment: @tkausl, is this always the case when declaration is present after main?

Comment: This has nothing to do with main. `Implicit declarations always assume int as return type.` Just don't do it. Its a warning for a reason.

Comment: @tkausl, In snippet 1, as `implicit declarations always assume int as return type`, compiler assumes that the return type is int (because there was no function declaration present ). When it encounters a function with float return type, it assumes it as a different function (due to function overloading?). Am i correct?

Comment: `it assumes it as a different function (due to function overloading?)` C has no overloading, hence the `error: conflicting types for 'fun'`.

Comment: The compiler processes the source code top-to-bottom. If it encounters the function call in line 5 but the function is declared in line 10, then for the call in line 5, it is implicitely declared.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller Gotcha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First snippet:

```
int main() {
    float val;
    val = fun(2, 4);
    printf("%f", val);
    
    return 0;
}
float fun(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

When you write `val = fun(2, 4);` in `main` the compiler has not yet encountered `float fun(int x, int y)`. Therefore it assumes that `fun` is declared like this: `int fun();` (function returning an `int` and taking any number of parameters of any type.

Then the compiler encounters `float fun(int x, int y)`, but as explained in the preceeding paragraph, the compiler assumes now that `fun` returns an `int`, hence the conflict.

If you put `float fun(int x, int y)` *before* `main`, the compiler encounters `float fun(int x, int y)` and now knows that `fun` returns a `float` and takes exactly two `int` arguments.

Implicit declarations are a thing of the past, and they shouldn't be used nowadays ever.

**BTW:**

There is no *undefined behaviour* involved here. *Undefined behaviour* is something completly different.

I suggest you read this: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Implicit declarations are *literally* a thing of the past, in that they are not supported by C99 or any later version of the language.  Many compilers continue to recognize it, but as (now) an extension serving backwards compatibility.

Comment: There's also an implicit conversion from `int` to `float` in `fun()` -- it's declared as returning `float`, but since `x` and `y` are `int`, `x+y` is also `int`. Seems like the compiler does the right thing here and converts `x+y` to `float`, but IMO it'd be better to `return (float)(x+y);` so that future readers understand that you really meant to return `float`.

Comment: "Therefore it assumes that fun is declared like this:" No it doesn't, it refuses to compile the code. "There is no undefined behaviour involved here" I believe there is explicitly UB as per 6.5.2.2 "If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type" /--/ "If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

> But in case of second snippet, i'm getting correct output.

No, it does not compile either. To save you from the head ache of troubleshooting code where the compiler has already found the bugs, ensure to use a conforming C compiler, see [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

When using a correctly configured conforming C compiler, we get this error:

> error: implicit declaration of function 'fun'

The reason why some compilers decide to generate an executable when not set to strict compliance mode is historical. 32 years old (ancient!) compilers had a feature called "implicit function declaration" and "implicit int". This meant that when the compiler encountered a function call to a function which had not yet been declared/defined, it guessed that the function would have a return type of `int`. Because why not - it could be the correct type in some cases!

And in case it isn't, we get undefined behavior and anything could happen. Such as the function returning a `float` but the caller treating the raw binary representation of that `float` as an `int`. Or the program crashing.

This language design flaw was removed from C in the C99 version released 23 years(!) ago.

There is probably no reason why you should be using ancient compiler modes, so just compile with the options given in the link above.

Comment: (And now I'm totally going to start using the abbreviation I just invented here: CCCCC - correctly configured conforming C compiler :) )

Comment: I'm using online c compiler https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @taurus05 Seems smelly. Use one with gcc and/or clang support where you can configure the compiler options manually. For example https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: @Lundin: I suggest that you simply write `5C` instead of `CCCCC`, as it is also common to write [`4X`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4X) instead of `XXXX`.

Comment: And don't mix it up with IOCCC. :-D